# how to make this URL case insensitive

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

Following is the content of my `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_speling.c>
CheckSpelling On
CheckCaseOnly On
</IfModule>
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L,NC]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

> Note: **blog** directory exist on server

I like to write a RewriteRule or any other thing, which can change or rewrite this `www.example.com/BLOG/anything-here/foo/bar` to `www.example.com/blog/anything-here/foo/bar`

in other words all i want is to change the case of word **BLOG** into lowercase **blog**

i tried to use `CheckCaseOnly On` but its not working, although its working for other words in the url, but its not working for this specific **blog** word, which is the rewritebase

Answer (score 0):

you may try something like this -

RewriteEngine On
RewriteMap lowercase int:tolower
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]  ##So that this rule is applied only if there's an Upper case in URI.
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /${lowercase:$1}

This should work.

Note - 'lowercase' is just a variable name and can be anything.

Comment: thanks but, RewriteMap do not work on bluehost shared server hosting plan